# Subpanel not getting open in suagarcrm 7.8 version

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I updated Sugar from version 7.6 to 7.8  i add some custom code in `subpanel-list.js` and it was working perfect in 7.6 version . But now in 7.8 version due to this code subpanel is not working . Can any one tell me the solutions for that.

I tried to ask this question to sugar support team but they told me that it is related to custom code , so need to ask to sugar developers.

I am providing my code which was working on 7.6 but due to this code now in 7.8 subpanel is not working.

```
({extendsFrom: 'SubpanelListView',

    //contextEvents: {"list:inviteportal:fire": "renderOnInvitePortal"}, 
    initialize: function(options) {
     //   this.dataViewName = options.name || 'subpanel-list';
        this._super("initialize", [options]);
         this.context.on('list:inviteportal:fire',this.renderOnInvitePortal, this);
    },
    renderOnInvitePortal: function(model){     
        app.api.call('read',app.api.buildURL(model.get('_module'),'read',{id:model.get('id')}),null,
        {
            success: function(data) {
                bean = app.data.createBean(data._module,data); 
                app.drawer.open({
                    layout : 'inviteportal',
                    context : {
                        create : true,
                        model : bean,
                        module : bean.get('_module')
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                return;
            }
        }         
    );
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , In subpanel-list.php in 7.7 version

```
'template' => 'recordlist',
```

Now in 7.8 version it is.

```
'template' => 'flex-list',
```